# Stylish Add-On: border-radius property breaking my CSS

Tags: css, stylish

I'm using the Stylish browser extension to create a custom dark theme for a website. In a recent update, the site owner came up with rounded corners for a lot of things, which is ugly as hell in my opinion, especially with input fields. However, when I try to apply `border-radius: 0px !important;` using Stylish, the input fields go nuts. It works fine on things like regular divs, but not on any kind of inputs, be it a regular `<input type=text>`, a `<textarea>` or even things like a `<select>`.

This is how a text area looks like without my custom CSS:

[image]

This is how it looks like with my custom CSS:

[image]

This is how it looks like when I add `border-radius: 0px !important;` to my CSS:

[image]

When `border-radius: 0px` is applied, all other `border` properties and `background` are ignored. Not even the site's native CSS properties are used. The browser just uses the standard look like there were no CSS rules defined for the textarea at all. `color` still works though.

It's like `border-radius` was *intended* to change everything. If I add it only on `:hover`, the input fields only go crazy on hover. I don't even have to use `0px`: The issue happens even when I use the same `6px` that the site's native CSS uses.

This is my whole CSS rule:

```
textarea, input[type="text"], .textbox {
    border-color: #282828 !important;
    border-width: 3px !important;
    border-style: solid !important;
    border-radius: 0px !important;
    background: #0F0F0F !important;
    color: grey !important;
}
```

What's really weird is the fact that `border-radius: 0px` causes no problems when added using the Firefox developer tools, so it seems to be a problem with stylish.

What's causing this madness? How can I fix it? Is there a workaround? The only idea I had is to use a custom JS that adds the property ...

Comment: Can you post site's CSS?

Comment: It's a forum, so the site's CSS is long as hell. The only relevant thing to this should be `border-radius: 6px` being applied to all kinds of inputs and buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh my god, removing `border-style: solid;` fixes everything. I have no clue why, but I am happy now.